# Creating Flag Variable based on negativity/positivity in R

Tags: r, variables

I am attempting to create a flag variable called Profit.flag that indicates whether a specific column in my dataset is profitable (>= 0) or not (<0). This is currently what I have but I am getting an error. Any help would be much obliged!

```
Profit = data.frame(S2$Profit)
Profit.flag=numeric(474)
for(i in Profit)
  {if (Profit[i] >= 0)
  {Profit.flag[i] == 1}
  else Profit.flag[i] == 0}
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and the desired output for that input. But looks like you might just want `Profit.flag <- (S2$Profit>=0) + 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need loop here. This should work:

```
Profit.flag <- as.integer(S2$Profit >= 0)
```

or

```
Profit.flag <- as.integer(Profit[,1] >= 0)
```

Comment: or `(S2$Profit >= 0)*1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
require(dplyr) 
df<- df %>%
         mutate(flag= ifelse(column>=0, 1, 0))
```

where df is your data frame and column- column name for which you want to check the value

Comment: @MonikaKastner MrFlick is indicating that you might want to edit your answer to include `require(dplyr)`

Comment: Not figured it could mean that, now I know :)